# Can be integrated jquery textcomplete with tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, integration, wysiwyg

I use [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) in my site. It work well with default textarea's but not work with tinymce. Can be integrated jquery-textcomplete with tinymce?

In the [official website](https://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/) jquery-textcomplete post or example integration with `wysiwyg editor` not said.

Thanks for answering!

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['stackoverflow', 'ҳайрат', 'english', 'маҳорат'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      if (word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== 0)
        return null;

      if (term[term.length-1] === term[term.length-1].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.toLocaleUpperCase(); // last char is upper = uppercase
      if (term[0] === term[0].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // first char is upper = capitalized
        
      return word; // default; is lowercase
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

<h3>Testing jquery textcomplete in input</h3>    
<p><input id="textcomplete" type="text"></p>
<h3>Testing jquery textcomplete in textarea with TinyMCE</h3>
<p><textarea></textarea></p>
```